# Ideas on how to proceed with a proof?

Tags: real-analysis, roots

Sorry if this is a nonspecific question - I can provide more details but at this point I need general ideas on a proof strategy.

So I recently reduced a rather difficult optimization problem to another problem whether a smooth function $f$ of three real variables $x,y,z$ has a solution for $x,y,z\geq0$, that is
$$
f(x,y,z)=0.
$$
Unfortunately, the function is a complicated and long algebraic expression containing square roots. From its form it is not obvious that the only non negative solution is whenever $y\geq0,z\geq0$ and $x=0$ which is the desired result and it is also supported by numerical evidence.

My **first** question is: What are the options now? What would your general strategy be? The standard calculus acrobatics like taking derivatives or Taylor expansion leads to even more complicated expressions. It seems to me that by reducing an optimization problem to a question whether a function is positive/negative is a great simplification.

I tried to set $y=y_0>0,z=z_0>0$ to see what expression I get and it is an algebraic equation with five roots (two complex, two negative and zero). The expression can be transformed into a polynomial equation but this involves squaring (obviously leading to more solutions than there is to the original eqaution $f(x,y_0,z_0)=0$) and moreover it is of degree $>4$ so no explicit solutions anyway.

My **second** question is: If nothing else, could the proof be concluded at this point? It is not the level of rigor I prefer since the result is not obvious by staring at $f$. On the other hand there must be a number of problems leading to explicitly ''unsolvable'' constraints. In a similar vein, some problems in calculus are solved up to an integral solution since the integral is not expressible in terms of elementary functions (this is a bit lame comparision I admit).

Comment: If you can prove that for any value of $y_0, z_0\geq 0$, the roots of your function (which is now a function of one variable) are either complex or negative (and one zero), then your proof is complete.

Comment: Oh, why is that? I intuitively thought about it but I was not sure why it is true. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to prove that if $f(x,y,z)=0$ and $x,y,z\geq 0$, then $x=0$. As I understand it, you have already proven this statement:

> For any value of $y_0,z_0\geq 0$, the function $g(x) = f(x,y_0,z_0)$
>   has two negative, two complex roots and one root at $x=0$.

Now, simply take any tuple $(x,y,z)$ such that $x,y,z\geq 0$ and $f(x,y,z) = 0$. Now construct the function $g(t) = f(t,y,z)$. Since you know that $g(x) = f(x,y,z)=0$, you know that $x$ is a root of the function $g$, but since all roots of this function are either complex, negative or equal to zero (and $x\geq 0\in \mathbb R$), this means that $x=0$.

This means that any tuple $(x,y,z)$ which solves $f(x,y,z) = 0$, must have the value of $x = 0$.

Comment: So I did not prove the statement in the grey box but thank you for your statement - this is what I thought to be true. Let me give an example of $g(x)$: $$g(x)=-20000 \text{x}^4+140000 \text{x}^3+228300 \text{x}^2+\sqrt{100 \text{x}^2+580 \text{x}+121} \left(2000 \text{x}^3-3600 \text{x}^2-4290 \text{x}+913\right)+24020 \text{x}-10043 $$. How can one easily argue about no positive solution of this?

Comment: @lamen: See my comment under my answer.

Comment: @lamen: And I don't know how on earth you know that this $g$ for example has two complex roots...

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without you showing even the general structure of your function, but there are a few simple but general strategies:

1. Bounding by a simpler function, using truncated series expansions or inequalities like AM-GM
2. Proving monotonicity in $x$ directly without finding the derivative
3. Splitting cases based on how the graph looks and 'smoothing' towards simple equality cases

Comment: So following 5xum's advice I can convert it toa single variable problem. But this is still a tricky function to study (at least for me). Please see above the example of $g(x)$. Any ideas how to apply your points 1 and 3?

Comment: Following (3), we can split into the cases of $x \in [0,3]$ and $x > 3$ according to roughly where the cubic multiplied by the sqrt changes sign. I believe the second case should be simple, and for the first case we can then follow (1) and try using $\sqrt{121+580x+100x^2} \in 11+\frac{290}{11}x-[0,\frac{36000}{1331}]x^2$ for $x \ge 0$, which can be proven by repeated differentiation, to get two polynomials as a window in which $g(x)$ must lie, which should then be easy enough to handle by differentiation.

Comment: This is to your question about complex roots: I had to calculate it numerically, I don't how can your method can be used to show that the greatest non negative root is zero and the rest is comlex/negative.

Comment: @lamen: Did you try what I said in my comment above? It does exactly what you want.